# Try and catch statement doesn't get me to try again

Tags: java, exception

i don't know why the try catch statement not working:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    protected static int intNum;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("[Shopping List] This is the shopping list GUI by Endercy.");
            System.out.println("[Shopping List] Controls are here:");
            System.out.println("[Shopping List] Type 1 to create a Shopping List");
            System.out.println("[Shopping List] Type 2 to enter a Shopping List name to view its contents");
            System.out.println("[Shopping List] Type 3 Add an item to your shopping list");
            System.out.println("[Shopping List] Type 4 to remove an item from your shopping list");
            System.out.println("[Shopping List] Type 5 to add a price to one of your items in your shopping list");
            intNum = scanner.nextInt();
            switch(intNum) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("test");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("test test");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("test test test");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("test test test test");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("test test test test test");
                    break;
                default:
                    while(true) {
                        System.out.println("I'm sorry, but this number is not on our controls list. Try again!");
                            try {
                                intNum = scanner.nextInt();
                            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                                System.out.println("Invalid Number, try again!");
                                intNum = scanner.nextInt();
                            }
                        switch(intNum) {
                            case 1:
                                System.out.println("test");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                System.out.println("test test");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                System.out.println("test test test");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                System.out.println("test test test test");
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                System.out.println("test test test test test");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
            }
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Thanks for trying out this thingy");
    }
}
```

this is the code, and i just want to do the InputMismatchException in case someone enter invalid stuff like 283479234729472983472984723 or a String etc.

but when i run it i enter stuff like that it doesn't let me try again with the scanner it just skips to:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "879857294729847917412942472394724237492734923"
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2264)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at com.endercy.challenges.java.arraylist.shoppinglist.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

and it doesn't give me to enter another one.

Comment: Is that exception from the second attempt? Because nothing stops it from erroring after the first try (you would need to loop until the input is valid)

Answer (score 0):

You should put another try catch blok to first scanner.nextInt method. I think the code does not pass there and throws exception there